# Dropdown menu blocking main nav on small desktop screens

Tags: css

AT solar-states.com, when we hover over the dropdown menu on small desktop screens it's opening up above the fold of the main nav, blocking the options. Any advice?

main menu with nothing opened:
[image: main menu with nothing opened]

menu opened on big desktop screen:
[image: menu opened on big desktop screen]

when opened up on small desktop screen
[image: when opened up on small desktop screen]

Comment: Hi there we need you to share your code in HTML and CSS that is related to your problem in order for us to debug it and help you fix your problem.

Comment: Share code and don't paste links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youu have an extra class that is added by JS when you go `.submenu:hover` that is adding a `margin-top` in negative. just try to cancel this margin width css:

```css
nav#navigation ul#menu-main > li > ul.sub-menu {
   margin-top:0 !important;
}
```